# Dictionary of Logic Functions

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, logic

I want to create a dictionary in c++ where I am supposed to keep a reference number and a logic function related to it, I thought could do like this sample:

```
map<int,..>func = {
   {1 = !},
   {2 = &&},
   {3 = ||}
};
```

Someone have an ideia how I could implement this?

Comment: you want logic operators operating on booleans or on any types?

Comment: how do you plan to use them? You have to distinguish between unary and binary operators somehow

Comment: I want to random sort these to create random boolean network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that `!`, `&&` and `||` are not functions. They are build in operators and as such you cannot store them in a map. You can however store functions in a map that apply those operators to their parameters.

For binary operators operating on boolean, it is as simple as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

std::map<int,std::function<bool(bool,bool)>> my_map{ 
    {1, [](bool a,bool b){ return a && b; } } 
};

int main(void) {
    std::cout << my_map[1](true,true);
}
```

However, it is a tiny bit more involved if the operators are supposed to work on arbitrary types and it is not clear why you want to mix unary (`!`) and binary operators.

Comment: This is very good, but it wasn't the ideia. Can't I use the dictionary to keep the logical functions?

Comment: @RitaCarolina why this wasnt the idea? `my_map` is storing the logical functions. Please explain why this is not what you want

Comment: @RitaCarolina you wont be able (at least not without major effort) to enable something along the line of `true my_map[1] true` if that is what you have in mind

Comment: @RitaCarolina The inbuilt boolean operators `&&`, `!` etc. are not functions. They are operators. You cannot store operators in a map. You can store functions (as this answer shows). You can still use this to build a random boolean network.

Comment: @MaxLanghof that might be part of the misunderstanding, updated the answer